Is there a way to simulate PowerBI's cards with SSRS
We have users on a DevExpress reporting solution that can do Cards (or KPI's) like PowerBI. That solution will no longer be used and I want to recreate their reports in SSRS. SSRS 2016 could do KPI's but this is on the 2019 version that doesn't.
Putting all the data that is on each card in a Matrix is fairly straightforward, but where the cards arrange themselves nicely in the available space, some next to one another, the matrix will just be a long vertical list that potentially stretch to multiple pages.
Is there a way to do something like a rectangle, where the bottom rows of a matrix will go to the right of existing matrix rows if it grows outside of the vertical limit of the rectangle?
